# Iterate through two Arrays VBscript

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop, vbscript

I have two arrays, the first one has similar values, and is in sorted order, the second array is basically a CSV map. I want to some how concatenate the values in my first array, so they are all grouped together, based on the second value of the Map

What I have:

```
arr1                            Map
----                            ---
 x                              x, 1
 x                              y, 1
 x                              z, 2
 y
 y
 z
```

What I want:

```
    newArr                            
    ----                            
 x x x y y, 1                                                         
 z , 2
```

My code:

```
For Each x in arr1
    For each y in Map
        line = Split(y, ",")
        If Instr(x, line(0)) Then
            Redim Preserve newArr(i)
            newArr(i) = newArr(i) & x
        ElseIf Instr(x, line(1)) Then
            Redim Preserve newArr(i)
            newArr(i) = newArr(i) & x
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

My logic was to compare the val in arr1 to map(0), if there were similarities, put it in an array, if there aren't, check map(1), if there is a match there, append it to that value in newArr(i). Only iterate if there are no matches. Obviously my code is not doing that. Thoughts?

Comment: `InStr` will return a integer with the position of the substring found in the string. It will not return `True` or `False`, so you cannot do this: `If Instr(x, line(0)) Then`. You need to, instead, check if position is higher than `0`, like this: `If Instr(x, line(0)) > 0 Then`. Plus, I don't understand why you are doing `newArr(i) = newArr(i) & x`. You have just ReDim your array, so obviously `newArr(i)` is empty and you could simply do `newArr(i) = x`. And I trust you are previously assigning a value to `i` before starting this loop, otherwise it won't work if the variable is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP asked if the array could be sorted alphabetically based of the map.

```
arr1 = Array("x","x","x","y","y","z")
Map = Array("x,B","y,B","z,A")
```

### [image]

```
Dim IndexList, DictKeys
Set IndexList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set DictKeys = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim arr1, Map, newArr, temp, x, y
arr1 = Array("x","x","x","y","y","z")
Map = Array("x,B","y,B","z,A")

For Each y In Map
    line = Split(y, ",")
    If Not IndexList.Contains(CStr(line(1))) Then IndexList.Add  CStr(line(1))
Next 

IndexList.Sort

For Each y In Map
    line = Split(y, ",")
    If Not DictKeys.Exists(line(0)) Then DictKeys.Add  line(0), IndexList.LastIndexOf(CStr(line(1)))
Next 

ReDim newArr(IndexList.Count - 1)

For Each y In arr1
    If IsEmpty(newArr(DictKeys(y))) Then
        ReDim temp(0)
    Else
        temp = newArr(DictKeys(y))
        ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
    End If
    temp(UBound(temp))= y
    newArr(DictKeys(y))  = temp
Next 

For i = 0 To UBound(newArr)
    temp = newArr(i )
    ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
    temp(UBound(temp))= i + 1
    newArr(i ) = temp  
Next

For Each x In newArr
    WScript.Echo Join(x , ",")
Next
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arr1, line, Map, newArr, temp, x, y
arr1 = Array("x","x","x","y","y","z")
Map = Array("x,1","y,1","z,2")

ReDim newArr(0)
ReDim temp(0)
newArr(0) = Array()

For Each y In Map
    line = Split(y, ",")
    i = line(1)
    If UBound(newArr) < i -1 Then 
        ReDim Preserve newArr(i - 1)
        newArr(i - 1) = Array()
    End If

    For Each x In arr1
        If x = line(0) Then
            temp = newArr(i - 1)
            ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
            temp(UBound(temp))= x
            newArr(i - 1) = temp            
        End If
    Next

Next    

For i = 0 To UBound(newArr)
    temp = newArr(i )
    ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp) + 1)
    temp(UBound(temp))= i + 1
    newArr(i ) = temp  
Next

For Each x In newArr
    WScript.Echo Join(x , ",")
Next
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, what about the 1 & 2?

Comment: Is there any way, to only get one "1" in the first line? The one is an identifier.

Comment: @tarki I just woke up and had forgot exactly what I did...lol.  My answer is updated.

Comment: is there anyway to make this more dynamic? Like what if for instance in the map, line(1) was a string, instead of an integer.

Comment: Such as:Array("x,A","y,A","z,B").  Would you want it sorted?  Or would you want the index incremented each time that there is a change in the string key?

Comment: Well, the second part of map is just a key. I need it to identify the values in arr1. They would be random strings.

Comment: If there is a change in string key, but it would have to be based on value, string key can go in order "B,A,B,B,B,B,B,A," should still return the same thing as if string key was just "A, B"

Comment: It needs to be sorted.  I would use a SortedList to index the map.  I will work on it but it'll probably be a couple of days.

Comment: So sort the map by the second value of the line? No problem, can you give me a quick psuedo code so I can work on it as well? :)

Comment: I'm at work right now.  I'll try and mock it up in about 5hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Dictionary Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) which stores data `key`, `item` pairs:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strRslt, x, y, z, i, arr1, map, line, newArr, auxDict, bFound, sNotFoundKey
strRslt      = ""     ' result used for final `SPLIT` and `ECHO`
sNotFoundKey = "#"    ' dictionary key used for items not found in map
arr1         = Array( "n","x","x","x","y","y","z")
map          = Array( "x,1","y,1","z,2")
set auxDict  = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each x in arr1
  bFound = False
  For Each y in Map
    line = Split( y, ",")
    If Not auxDict.Exists( line( 1)) Then auxDict.Add( line( 1)), "" 
    If Instr( x, line( 0)) Then
      auxDict( line( 1)) = auxDict( line( 1)) & " " & x
      bFound = True
      ''' Exit For ''' 
    End If
  Next
  If Not bFound Then
    If Not auxDict.Exists( sNotFoundKey) Then auxDict.Add( sNotFoundKey), ""
    auxDict( sNotFoundKey) = auxDict( sNotFoundKey) & " " & x
  End If 
Next
newArr = auxDict.Keys
For i = 0 to UBound( newArr)
  strRslt = strRslt & vbNewLine & Trim( auxDict( newArr( i))) & ", " & newArr( i) 
Next
newArr = Split( strRslt,vbNewLine)  ' final `SPLIT`

Wscript.Echo strRslt                ' give publicity to result 
Wscript.Quit
```

**Result**:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\39111519.vbs

x x x y y, 1
z, 2
n, #

==>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with arrays?

Comment: @tarki Thomas' answer seems to show a way to do this with arrays…

Comment: Is there anyway to make newArr a dict obj, I still would want to be able to access the keys and items separately?